# Are Subjects Joined by And Singular or Plural?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, verbs, verb-agreement

Fresh air and peace of mind are on the cards. are we supposed to use "is" here or "are". could anyone tell me about the usage, please?

Comment: Consider the simpler sentence "Alice and Bob is/are here". Which of is/are would you use? The phrase "fresh air and peace of mind" isn't so well-known that it would be considered singular.

Comment: Oh, thank you for helping me out! actually I read it somewhere and got confused whether to use "are" or "is".

Comment: Thank you for clearing my confusion.

Comment: @WeatherVane As would, for example "Fish and chips is my favourite Friday-night supper".

Comment: The solution is to substitute a pronoun for the subject. The subject is *"Fresh air and peace of mind"*: which pronoun are you going to use? **It** or **they**?